# Too much network request does not fetches data from server?

Tags: android

I am making an e-commerce android application and faced a major issue.I am fetching data for display through remote server and using JSON format.There will be many images may be 40-60 images and some text content for a activity.Now what i do uptil now is that firstly i fetches json data from server which also contains image link with name in it.After that using glide i fetches all the images and show in it.During development phase,it works fine on  localhost but when i deployed all backened files on server then a major issue arises.It does not fetches data and takes too long.My backened API is working i checked them in browser and postman.What i am doing wrong here ? Does too much network request gives this issue?And main point is that server and all the php and sql files are working fine.

Comment: `Does too much network request gives this issue?` Yep and also consider the clients internet speed.

Comment: Client internet speed is fine .How can i resolve too much network request issue then ? Kindly give me good solution please

Comment: Probably minimize your network calls and only synchronize the data that are necessary. But honestly I don't have a silver bullet answer.

Comment: Sorry ! but i doesn not understand what do u mean to synchronize data? will u please elaborate